# Binding to ObservableCollection.Count doesn't update when OC is updated

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-toolkit

EDIT: The binding works properly if I remove `Minimum="1"` from the XAML... could this be a SL Toolkit problem?

I'm attempting to bind the value of a NumericUpDown from the Silverlight Toolkit to the Count of an ObservableCollection.

In the constructor of my ViewModel, I add items to the collection and the bindings accordingly update the View. However, the value in the NumericUpDown does not change (it stays at 1).

Interestingly, if I edit the binding while the designer is open and IntelliSense runs, the value does update to the correct value (in the designer).

Have I done something wrong here?

**Binding Code**

```
<toolkit:NumericUpDown x:Name="numberOfCubesUpDown" IsEnabled="True" Maximum="9" Minimum="1" Style="{StaticResource ButtonSpinnerHorizontalStyle}" Value="{Binding Path=Cubes.Count}" Height="30" FontSize="14">
  <i:Interaction.Triggers>
     <i:EventTrigger EventName="ValueChanged">
        <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding ChangeNumberOfCubesCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"></cmd:EventToCommand>
     </i:EventTrigger>
  </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</toolkit:NumericUpDown>
```

**ViewModel Binding Definition** CubeSet implements ObservableCollection

```
public CubeSet Cubes
    {
        get { return _cubes; }

        set
        {
            if (_cubes == value) { return; }
            _cubes = value;
        }
    }
```

**Where I change the CubeSet**

```
        Cubes = new CubeSet();
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) { Cubes.Add(new Cube()); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your class need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface and raise the PropertyChanged event in the setter.

Something like this:

```
 using System.ComponentModel;

namespace Sample.ViewModels
{
    public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        #endregion

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and your setter/getter would be like this

```
public CubeSet Cubes
{
    get { return _cubes; }

    set
    {
        if (_cubes == value) { return; }
        _cubes = value;

        OnPropertyChanged("Cubes");
    }
}
```

If you want the binding to update, you should set the value through the setter method. Of course you can manually raise the OnPropertyChanged event anywhere you want within the class and have your View check for the updated value.

Also, make sure to set the Mode on the binding. I believe by default, it is set to OneWay.

EDIT: Sorry, I somehow forgot it's an ObservableCollection. Perhaps you have the wrong DataContext.

Comment: I think the DataContext is correct, because of that quirk I mentioned with the Designer when IntelliSense kicks in... but for some reason PropertyChanged isn't firing when the ObservableCollection (CubeSet) is update.

Comment: Hm, I would try to write a getter that return collection  count value and manually call OnPropertyChanged("Count") whenever you add or remove an item from the list. This means you have to override the ObservableCollection add/remove/set method. If that still doesn't work, then it must be something else.